# How to get this $\beta$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question:** If $5^{40}$ is divided by $11$ then the remainder is $\alpha$ and when $2^{2003}$ is divided by $17$ , then the remainder is $\beta$. Then the value of $\beta-\alpha$ is ?

**Making an attempt:**  I used he cyclic property to calculate $\alpha$. That is checking the remainders of $5^0,5^1,5^2....$ Upon division by $11$.

$$5^0/11, remainder =1$$
$$5^1/11, remainder =5$$
$$5^2/11, remainder =3$$
$$5^3/11, remainder =4$$
$$5^4/11, remainder =9$$
$$5^5/11, remainder =1$$
$$5^6/11, remainder =5$$

Therefore the cycle repeats itself after $5 $ terms. thus $5^{40}$ divided by $11$ should be giving a remainder of $1$. Thus $\alpha=1$

But i tried using the same for getting $\beta$ but the cycle looks too big for manual computation. any help here?

**NOTE: Calculators weren't allowed in this test.**

Comment: There are only 17 possible remainders for dividing by 17.  So it cam't be too big.  Maybe bigger than one would like,  but it is possible.  Consider what happens if you allow negative "remainders".$ 2^4 =16=17-1$. So $2^8=(17-1)^2=17^2-2*17+1$ has remainder 1.  That's not too large at allď

Comment: @fleablood. It is big when you have to solve the whole problem in 2-3 minutes.

Comment: If you know FLT you know $2^{16} $ has remainder 1.  And if you don't know FLT you know 2^4 has -1 remainder so 2^8 will have 1 as a remainder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $2^{16}\equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ 17)$, so $$2^{2003}\equiv2^{16*125+3}\equiv 2^3\equiv 8 \ \ (\text{mod} \ 17)$$
You can check out [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Can you please explain the usage of that (mod).. term? I have seen it being used in many questions. Any suitable tutorial? Thanks for the asnwer btw.

Comment: $a\equiv b \ \ (\ \text{mod} \ c \ )$ means the remainder of $a$ divided by $c$ is $b$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know Fermats Little Theorem or Euler's theorem.

Oh, welll...

$2^4=16=17-1$.  So $2^8=17^2-2*17+1$ has remainder 1 when divided by $17$.  So $2^{2003}=(2^8)^{250}*2^3$ will have remainder $8$.